# builtin AJAX support in django

Tags: jquery, python, angularjs, ajax, django

It is a pretty newbie question but is there a builtin AJAX support in django?
What I need is the following: I have a list if the user clicks on an element then another list should be displayed next to the first one that contains the child elements of the selected element and so on. So it is a tree structure but I dont want to use a tree as theoritacally there would be only just a few level but lots of elements on one level.
The django template can give us a very good tool to build webpage but can something similar in django be used for AJAX requests?
I could use a javacript framework (angularjs) or js library (react js) but in this case django would be only the REST layer. I'd want to use django as a view layer too.
Can I?

Thank you!
V.

Comment: Of course you can use ajax calls. Django template is nothing but html files only. Add your jquery calls in `<script>` tag to fetch the data.

Comment: Thanks for the response! What I want to avoid is to create the list with django template and with jquery too. Or just use only jquery? But in this case the django will provide a REST service only and all the UI will be in Jquery, wont they?